# Update postgresql if the key exist with php

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Im converting my php app to work with postgresql instead of mysql.

Before I had this function using PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(id,name,info) VALUES(:id,:name,:info) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=:name,info=:info");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':name' => $name, :info' => $info));
```

If the key does not exist it creates a new entry, or else it updates the entry.

How is it possible to do somewhat the same with postgresql?

I have read some articles, but no one is clear on what I have to do. Do I need to write an trigger or rule for this?

Or do I write an check in php if the entry/id exist, and determine if it should update or create new?

Im using postgres 9.1.8

Comment: http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/

Comment: Could someone explain where I use the "CREATE FUNCTION" ? Do I do it in the psql shell, make a file on the server, use it in php? Do I have to write function for every table I need to update?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert

You can run the merge command trought the prepare then execute it.

I guess this should work